# Setting registry values in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Tags: windows, permissions, registry, windows-vista, access-denied

The Administrator user account I am running my compiled program in has `Special` (`Full` is allow'd, amongst all other permissions listed also allow'd, in the `Permission Entry` dialog) permission access to the above registry key.

I can alter the values in this key manually via `regedit` without issue.

However, when running the program in a Windows Vista Home Premium SP2 32-bit install, an attempt by this program to do a `RegSetValue` to the above registry value, is `ACCESS DENIED`.

Does anyone know why (Can provide a `procmon` trace, if helpful)?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit program running on a 64-bit OS?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - It is a 32bit OS, but even though I believe this negates the point of your question, how can one tell if a compiled program is 32-bit or 64-bit (Not through the original languages API/compiler)?

Comment: Have you made sure you are running the program elevated?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I didn't realise this would be required, when running under an administrator account. However, have just tried the same program on an Win XP SP3 32bit install, with the same `ACCESS DENIED` error happening with the same action, on the same registry key.

Comment: So, on the WinXP system, can you make the same change with the same account using regedit?  Can you show your code?

Comment: I can make the same change, on the same account, using regedit, for both Win xp and Vista installs above. Unfortunately, cannot share code. Had hoped that there would only be a small number of reasons for this to happen.

Comment: I suspect either a trivial bug in the call to `RegSetValueEx` (or perhaps `RegCreateKeyEx`) or a locking issue.  Can you reproduce the problem in a separate program that does nothing but the write to that key, and share *that* code?